# How can I use the mas5calls function without getting an error message? in R

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor

My code:

```
setwd("C:/A549_ALI/4_tert-Butanol (22)/")
list.celfiles()
my.affy=ReadAffy()
dim(exprs(my.affy))
```

Output:

```
    Show in New Window
     [1] "(46) 22-B1-1_(miRNA-4_0).CEL"   
     [2] "(47) 22-B1-2_(miRNA-4_0).CEL"   
     [3] "(48) 22-B1-3_(miRNA-4_0).CEL"   
     [4] "(49) 22-R1-1_(miRNA-4_0).CEL"   
     [5] "(50) 22-NEC 1-1_(miRNA-4_0).CEL"
     [6] "(51) 22-B2-1_(miRNA-4_0).CEL"   
     [7] "(52) 22-B2-2_(miRNA-4_0).CEL"   
     [8] "(53) 22-B2-3_(miRNA-4_0).CEL"   
     [9] "(54) 22-R2-1_(miRNA-4_0).CEL"   
    [10] "(55) 22-NEC 2-1_(miRNA-4_0).CEL"
    [11] "(56) 22-B3-1_(miRNA-4_0).CEL"   
    [12] "(57) 22-B3-2_(miRNA-4_0).CEL"   
    [13] "(58) 22-B3-3_(miRNA-4_0).CEL"   
    [14] "(59) 22-R3-1_(miRNA-4_0).CEL"   
    [15] "(60) 22-NEC 3-1_(miRNA-4_0).CEL"
    [1] 292681     15
```

Up to here everything works but than I get this error message:

```
background correction: mas 
PM/MM correction : mas 
expression values: mas 
background correcting...'getOption("repos")' replaces Bioconductor standard repositories, see '?repositories' for details

replacement repositories:
    CRAN: https://cran.rstudio.com/

Error in getCdfInfo(object) : 
  Could not obtain CDF environment, problems encountered:
Specified environment does not contain miRNA-4_0
Library - package mirna40cdf not installed
Bioconductor - mirna40cdf not available
```

I have already tried to install this package, but I can't find it on the Bioconductor website.

Now I do not know how to proceed. Is there any other way to use the mas5calls function?

I use R 4.2.2.

Thanks for all answers.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have given as much code as I could.

Answer (score 0):

This simply means that the package with the cdf-env built upon the chip description (CDF) - file for this type of MicroArray data is not distributed through Bio-conductor. It seems that Affymetrix is not providing those anymore, but you can find them on GEO. (click on the platform and than under "Supplementary file" . Alternatively ask the person you got the data from if they can provide you with the relevant CDFs. Use `cfdName()`  to check which ones you need.
Once you obtained the CDF you can build the R package ( `mirna40cdf` in your case) that `affy` needs using the `makecdfenv` package you can install from Bioconductor. You could also try to use another package called `oligo` and see if it supports your data.